# Suspicious wifi networks from distant places and hotels

Tags: wifi, macos, spoofing

When I check my Macbook's network settings, I see some unfamiliar wifi networks from distant places like famous hotels. It's impossible to connect to those networks because I've never been to those places before.

Is it evidence that shows that I'm hacked?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's just an evidence there are other Wifi network around you. These other Wifi networks most probably belong to other people or companies. You would be able to connect to them only if they give you the associated password, without that you can only see that they are here without being able to actually connect to them.

Comment: But it's impossible for me to see that networks. They are in totally different cities which I never been there before. For example one of them is a famous hotel's wifi who's is located in a different city.

Comment: Wifi network names can be chosen freely by their owners. Even if there are indeed some bad practice involving using the same name as some other networks, as long as you do not connect to an unknown and untrusted network then you are safe (one cannot hack your system just by showing an unknown or strange network name). To be on the safe side, you may list the networks actually known to your computer and deleted all unusued ones and ensure that the remaining ones need a password (ie. no public wifi hotspot remains in your list).

Comment: Is it possible to see attackers network name in my wifi network list?

Comment: I've edited your question to highlight the "famous hotel" thing which may indicate that someone is trying to build a fake access point to trick computer knowing this network to connect as if it was the genuine hotel wifi access point. However, as said above, as long as you do not connect to these networks you are safe. Without specific means and technical knowledge, it will be difficult to get more information regarding the potential attacker, so the better will just be to stay safely out of this networks and ensure your known network list (you may need to check your cellphone too) is clean.